# Animating when content loads in Selte

Tags: javascript, animation, svelte

I have a website which lists hiking tours as cards in Svelte. I use {#each} to generate the cards:

```
{#each tours as tour}
    <Card {tour} />
{/each}
```

The contents of the cards are grabbed from a separate file in the directory, I'm not using APIs. I wanted to have animation for them when the website loads, for each to generate one-by-one. I tried

```
import { fade, fly } from 'svelte/transition';
```

and added this to the main div of the card component:

```
in:fly={{ y: 200, duration: 400 }} out:fade
```

But this only animates this way if the content is removed, not when loading the page.

Comment: *for each to generate one-by-one* - In case you mean the cards should transition in one after the other the index of the #each block could be used to set `delay: 100*index`

Answer (score 0):

There might be a better method, but you could set a flag to `true` in `onMount` and use an `{#if}` wrapper using the flag.

```js
let mounted = false;
onMount(() => mounted = true);
```

```html
{#if mounted}
  <div in:fly={{ y: 200, duration: 400 }} out:fade> ...
```

Comment: Could you clarify a little?

Comment: See edit, it really is not complicated.